# how to reduce the complexity of this code which has if else

Tags: javascript, node.js

What can be done to make the code below simpler?

There is a if-else loop in this code, but could it be reduced to the minimum number of lines?

What could we do to reduce this code's complexity??

```
let android_devices = '';
    let ios_devices = '';
    let web_devices = '';
    if (location_id == '') {
      android_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
        where: {
          channel: 'ANDROID',
          ref: headerData?.ref,
        },
      });
      ios_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
        where: {
          channel: 'IOS',
          ref: headerData?.ref,
        },
      });
      web_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
        where: {
          channel: 'WEBSITE',
          ref: headerData?.ref,
        },
      });
    } else {
      android_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
        where: {
          channel: 'ANDROID',
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        },
      });
      ios_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
        where: {
          channel: 'IOS',
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        },
      });
      web_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
        where: {
          channel: 'WEBSITE',
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        },
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple of things you can do:

1. Set a variable equal to `location_id` or `headerData?.ref`, depending on whether `location_id` is `""`, and then reuse it in the `count` calls. Just doing that would cut the code in half, making it much more maintainable:

   ```
   const ref = location_id == "" ? headerData?.ref : location_id;
   let android_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
       where: {
           channel: "ANDROID",
           ref,
       },
   });
   let ios_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
       where: {
           channel: "IOS",
           ref,
       },
   });
   let web_devices = await PRISMA.customers.count({
       where: {
           channel: "WEBSITE",
           ref,
       },
   });
   ```
2. Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to query the counts and then assign them to variables via [iterable destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). (There's another kind, which is object destructuring, but for this we'd want iterable destructuring.) Like this:

   Like this:

   ```
   const ref = location_id == "" ? headerData?.ref : location_id;
   let [android_devices, ios_devices, web_devices] = await Promise.all(
       ["ANDROID", "IOS", "WEBSITE"].map((channel) => PRISMA.customers.count({
           where: {
               channel,
               ref,
           },
       })
   ));
   ```

   Note that it's important for th earray we're calling `map` on and the variables we're assigning to be in the same order. (`Promise.all` preserves order, so we know the count we request for `"ANDROID"` will be at index 0 of the result.)

Comment: *(Oops, editing error in #1. If you still see `headerDaa?.ref` in the calls to `count`, hit refresh.)*